# orderBy pipe for an array?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have an array of chats which have an array of messages, every single message has the property `receviedTime`.

I want to order my chat list by the `receviedTime` of its last message.
I am able to take the `receviedTime` of my last message in this way:

```
chat.messages[chat.messages.length - 1].receivedTime
```

In my Ionic angular app I'd like to use the pipe like:

```
{{let chat of chats | myOrderByPipe : 'chat.messages[chat.messages.length - 1].receivedTime'  }}
```

How can I order my chats by this attribute?

Comment: Can you show Data sample of your array.

Comment: It's an array of chats with some attibutes, like id, sender etc.. and this array containes another array of messages